Connecting many wires to Vcc
How can we make a common horizontal connecting point on a breadboard? We are trying to design a 3 bit synchronous counter using JK flipflops, in which most of the pins are get connected to Vcc. We are confused as to how to connect all those pins to Vcc.
I'm attaching the picture of what we did.


The breadboard has supply buses for this purpose. They are the horizontal red and blue lines.
One VCC wire to beadboard bus, maybe the red bus, and on the breadboard, neat wires going vertically from bus to correct IC pin.

Sorted! Thanks @justme
